# Adding cells to the next empty row of a excel sheet in Apache POI JAVA

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am working on a project that imports information from an excel file and then saves this in a second file. 
I get the following variables and I need these to be stored in a new row as separate cells

`userID = "" + importUsers.getSheetAt(0).getRow(counter).getCell(5);
computername = "" + importUsers.getSheetAt(0).getRow(counter).getCell(21);
location = "" + importUsers.getSheetAt(0).getRow(counter).getCell(14);
migID = "" + importUsers.getSheetAt(0).getRow(counter).getCell(0);`

I then create an instance of enterInfo.java

```
new enterInfo(userID, computername, location,migID,row);
```

Which leads to this class

```
public class enterInfo extends JFrame{

    public enterInfo(String userID, String computername, String location, String migID, int row) throws InvalidFormatException, IOException  {
        System.out.println("adding...");

        File workbookFile = new File("C:\\Users\\strinca1\\Decomp\\activeUsers.xlsx.xlsx");
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(workbookFile);
        Workbook activeUsers = WorkbookFactory.create(file);
        Row reihe = activeUsers.getSheetAt(0).createRow((short)row);
        // Create a cell and put a value in it.
        Cell cell = reihe.createCell(0);
        cell.setCellValue(1);

    }
}
```

It is however not adding anything to `activeUsers.xlsx.xlsx`

I can  not find where I am going wrong

Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: Do you actually write the modified `Workbook` back to a file ?

Comment: Use `activeUsers.write(new FileOutputStream(filename))`. The POI workbook does not automatically flush changes to disk like you are assuming.